# Call Angular directive function from another modules controller

Tags: angularjs

I would like to add event listeners to a directive in one module and I'd like to call that function from a controller in another module. How do I achieve that? I've added some pseudo code below. Hope it is clear what I'd like to achieve.

```
( function() {
    var myApp = angular.module( "myApp", [ "anotherModule" ] );

    myApp.directive( "myDirective", function( $document ) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function( scope, element, attr ) {
                var listenerCallback;

                var addListener = function( callback ) {
                    listenerCallback = callback;
                };

                // At an event I will call listenerCallback();
            }   
        };
    } );

    var anotherModule = angular.module( "anotherModule", [] );
    anotherModule.controller( "myController", [ "$scope", function( $scope ) {
        // Here i'd like to access the addListener function in myDirective
    } ] );
} )();
```

Comment: Can inject a service into both, or use scope broadcast events

Comment: Good point. A service could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you are approaching this "the Angular way". Directives and Controllers should avoid interacting directly, in favour of interfacing through the directive's DOM interface. This still works, even if there are multiple modules.

Typically, instead you'd use `scope: { listenerCallback: '&' }` to the directive Object. This may look like:

```
myApp.directive( "myDirective", function( $document ) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: { listenerCallback: '&' },
        link: function( scope, element, attr ) {
            // At an event I will call scope.listenerCallback();
        }   
    };
} );
```

The callback is implemented in the Controller, as you mentioned:

```
anotherModule.controller( "myController", [ "$scope", function( $scope ) {
    $scope.testCallback = function(){ /* your callback function */ };
} ] );
```

This would be bound through the DOM:

```
<div my-directive listener-callback="testCallback();">button label</div>
```

Here's an example, using your base code and two modules: http://jsfiddle.net/fmvh7vht/

If you're trying to attach multiple callbacks, consider passing via the scope a `Promise`, or an Array of callback functions.

Basically, as far as I've seen, there tends not to be a reason to actually reach into the directives and use their contents. Doing so would be considered an anti-pattern, and would be both confusing (later, during code maintenance) and fragile. Instead these entities usually interact via their shared/bound `scope` interface.